# Orientation media query not working on iPad mini

Tags: css, ipad, media

This small HTML code represents my HTML5 page very clearly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Pebble Go</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
                html, body {
                    background: #222;
                }
            }
            @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
                html, body {
                    background: #000;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </body>  
</html>
```

And so, on desktop browsers, Android tables and phones - it's working fine. But on iPad mini - it is not! … Result is - background is always gray. So my question is:

Why is this media query not working on iPad mini … ??? …

PS: I know that I have to use the max-device-width property as well, but I have a big reason not to do it! …

The requirement for this page is to be 100% wide and high, and I decided to:

1. Make the default CSS rules for landscape mode;
2. Define rules for different widths in landscape mode;
3. Define the portrait variants, relying basically on "orientation: portrait", and define different widths as well.

I did this! It's working! … Except the iPad mini !!! … And if I use max-device-width or something like this - then I'll be in a situation where I'll have to write different rules for landscape - different widths, portrait mode - different widths, and then mobile devices - landscape and portrait … !!! ….

Answer (score 10):

The problem appeared to be caused by the clause in the meta tag for the viewport, and more specifically: "height=device-height". Removing it made everything work normal :) ...

Comment: I know this was a while back, but finding this really saved me! Couldn't for the life of me figure it out! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem :) ... I know it's very lame :D ... but I decided to share it anyway ... and apparently it was a good idea ;)